# React native android emulator doesn't run application

Tags: android, react-native

Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.

> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score -1):

You need to IDE Android Studio to sync version of Gradle which was used in your app. 
 It is recommend to use IDE to checking the error when you are building the app by using React native because it's hardly to read the error message from console log. Don't forget add ignore gradle file in `.gitignore` to avoid these changes in Git.